# using a foreign library in sbcl - uffi or cffi?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I am an struggling with using a C++ library I have just sucessfully
compiled on ubuntu in sbcl.

I have tried to use the .h file parser 'ah2cl' but from the
documentation it is not clear if I require UFFI or CFFI (is there a
difference?). My attempts to use the dummy test library and the
dummy header file provided with 'ah2cl' have failed. I get a message
about a missing CALLBACK package from sbcl. But does sbcl not support
callback natively ?

Is there another .h file parser that I should use for this
kind of task ?

Comment: AH2CL's [web page](http://hocwp.free.fr/ah2cl/) states that: "It produce (at the moment) ffi (foreign function interface) for **clisp** and for **uffi** (but callbacks are well tested **only with clisp and cmucl**)". So in the case of SBCL it's not tested well.

Also please take a look at CFFI [wrapper generators](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/html_node/Wrapper-generators.html#Wrapper-generators): [SWIG](http://www.cliki.net/SWIG) and [Verrazano](http://common-lisp.net/project/fetter/).

Comment: Ok, will try it with those other two. thanks

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try [CFFI's groveller](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/html_node/The-Groveller.html), which parses header files to produce the corresponding CFFI bindings. BTW, UFFI is basically deprecated in favour of CFFI for a while now.